# GeometryReader Spacing inside ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a view like this:

```
ScrollView {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.red
    }
    .frame(height: 0)
    Group {
        Text("B")
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

There is a spacing between `GeometryReader` and the `Group`. Can we remove that spacing without setting some hardcode padding value? I tried setting `frame(height: 0)` to that `Color.red` as well, but that spacing is still there. My goal is to observe the offset change, I followed this tutorial https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/scrollview-offset/, but I don't know why we need to put `.padding(.top, -8)`.

[image]

Comment: `ScrollView { VStack(spacing: 0) { } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `VStack` to customize the spacing:

```swift
ScrollView { 
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ... 
    } 
}
```